# No traffic flows through Wireguard on Ubuntu 20.04.2

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard

I've been using Wireguard as a VPN on my RPi 4B for a while now, and this week I noticed it ain't working anymore. By not working I mean it connects but no traffic flows through. I reinstalled pivpn a couple of times and went through their FAQ but I can't figure out what changed and what's not working. During this period all I did was do the normal system updates, and update my docker containers on the machine: Home Assistant, Zigbee2MQTT, Eclipse Mosquito and PiHole.

```
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1034-raspi aarch64)

::: Generating Debug Output
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu: Name or service not known
::::            PiVPN debug              ::::
=============================================
::::            Latest commit            ::::
commit d7771c251418fa443869397d46f93c5b0c197558
Author: 4s3ti <4s3ti@protonmail.com>
Date:   Sat Feb 6 23:04:11 2021 +0100

    Merge branch test into master

    fixes #1234
    ci/cd fixes and improvements
=============================================
::::        Installation settings        ::::
PLAT=Ubuntu
OSCN=focal
USING_UFW=0
IPv4dev=eth0
install_user=ubuntu
install_home=/home/ubuntu
VPN=wireguard
pivpnPORT=51820
pivpnDNS1=192.168.3.5
pivpnDNS2=1.1.1.1
pivpnHOST=REDACTED
INPUT_CHAIN_EDITED=0
FORWARD_CHAIN_EDITED=1
pivpnPROTO=udp
pivpnDEV=wg0
pivpnNET=10.6.0.0
subnetClass=24
ALLOWED_IPS="0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0"
UNATTUPG=1
INSTALLED_PACKAGES=()
=============================================
::::  Server configuration shown below   ::::
[Interface]
PrivateKey = server_priv
Address = 10.6.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
### begin Pixel5 ###
[Peer]
PublicKey = Pixel5_pub
PresharedKey = Pixel5_psk
AllowedIPs = 10.6.0.2/32
### end Pixel5 ###
=============================================
::::  Client configuration shown below   ::::
[Interface]
PrivateKey = Pixel5_priv
Address = 10.6.0.2/24
DNS = 192.168.3.5, 1.1.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = server_pub
PresharedKey = Pixel5_psk
Endpoint = REDACTED:51820
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0
=============================================
::::    Recursive list of files in       ::::
::::    /etc/wireguard shown below       ::::
/etc/wireguard:
configs
keys
wg0.conf

/etc/wireguard/configs:
Pixel5.conf
clients.txt

/etc/wireguard/keys:
Pixel5_priv
Pixel5_psk
Pixel5_pub
server_priv
server_pub
=============================================
::::            Self check               ::::
:: [OK] IP forwarding is enabled
:: [OK] Iptables MASQUERADE rule set
:: [OK] Iptables FORWARD rule set
:: [OK] WireGuard is running
:: [OK] WireGuard is enabled (it will automatically start on reboot)
:: [OK] WireGuard is listening on port 51820/udp
```

Does anyone have a clue where should I start debugging? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out what the problem was. My ISP reset the GPON Modem which switched back to NAT mode instead of bridge mode. So the connection wasn't actually established but it was "active" somehow inside the Wireguard client.